# Testing Quartz JDBC Job Store

Tags: jdbc, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am using Quartz JDBC Job store (org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX) and MySQL for scheduling jobs.

I have the following setup:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=foo
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.user=user
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.password=*****
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.maxConnections=5
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.validateOnCheckout=true
org.quartz.dataSource.foo.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

I am able to schedule a job with Quartz picking up the job from the database when the time is due.

There are some jobs that can be scheduled up to 3 or 4 weeks in the future. How do I test this?

Right now I go manually change the system time. For example, if I schedule a job to run on 2/5/2013 12:45 PM, then I go change the system clock time to 2/5/2013 12:43 PM, then wait for a couple of minutes to see if Quartz picks up the job from the DB. This works fine for me.

I don't want to change the system clock time every time I need to test. Is there a better way to do this?

I noticed that changing the system time frequently sometimes messes up with Quartz with some jobs not picked up.

Comment: Do you really have to schedule jobs such far in future? Why can't you schedule jobs to run in a few seconds/minutes time? Would it be not sufficient for testing the scheduling?

Comment: You can check getNextFireTime().  I think you'll have to trust that Quartz is going to do the right thing if it's been scheduled properly.  You still will want to test that the job it's scheduled to run is working correctly.

Comment: @harpun - I was able to test jobs to run in a few minutes/hours and days. I have to support the feature for up to a month. I wanted to test all possible scenarios including those that are scheduled to run in 3 weeks.

Comment: Then I support @JoshuaMartell's idea to test getNextFireTime() and focus on testing the jobs themselves. The tricky cases with scheduling may involve times around DST time changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Quartz TriggerUtils](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html) methods to find out whether the future executions are the expected.

More specifically the `computeFireTimes(org.quartz.spi.OperableTrigger trigg, Calendar cal, int numTimes)` method returns a list of Dates that are the next fire times of a Trigger.

I hope this helps.